# WiX DifxApp error on driver package install: Could not get services associated with driver package

Tags: wix, driver, windows-7-x64, inf, minifilter

The driver I am attempting to install is a Kernel Mini-Filter driver for Windows 7x64. The machine I am testing the installer on is in test mode and the driver files and .cat file are all signed with a certificate I made. I followed the instructions [HERE](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/installing-filter-drivers-with-difxapp-and-a-wix-v3-msi/) and I am still unable to get the driver to install. I made sure to add `DriverPackageType = FileSystemMinifilter` to the `[version]` section of the .inf file.

Here is an excerpt from my WiX installer xml:

```
        <Directory Id="Driver" Name="Driver">
          <Component Id="MY-DRIVER-NAME" Guid="MY-GUID">
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE1_SYS"
              Name="DriverFile1.sys"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_sys_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"
              KeyPath="yes"/>
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE2_SYS"
              Name="DriverFile2.sys"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_sys_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"
              KeyPath="yes"/>
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE3_SYS"
              Name="DriverFile3.sys"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_sys_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"
              KeyPath="yes"/>
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE4_SYS"
              Name="DriverFile4.sys"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_sys_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"
              KeyPath="yes"/>
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE_INF"
              Name="DriverFile.inf"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_inf_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"/>
            <File
              Id="DRIVER_FILE_CAT"
              Name="DriverFile.cat"
              DiskId="1"
              Source="path_to_cat_file"
              Vital="yes"
              System="yes"
              ReadOnly="yes"/>
            <difx:Driver Legacy="yes"/>
          </Component><!--LEGDriver-->
```

The "Id", "Name", and "Source" paths have been changed (I'm not actually using the values shown above it is just an example). I have no problem building the installer. When I run it with `msiexec /i MyMsi.msi /l*v install.log` I see the error `DIFXAPP: ERROR: Could not get services associated with driver package`

Then it tries to undo the changes and runs into a few more errors:

```
ERROR: Unable to revert to a previous driver store for service ''.
ERROR: Unable to open service '' to delete it because of error 0x7B
```

The .inf file has no problem installing with the command:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 path-to-inf\infname.inf
```

It also successfully installs via 'right-click install'.

Adding the 'RUNDLL32.EXE' command above as a custom action ExeCommand to my WiX installer instead of using DifxApp works when installing the .msi file on the machine manually, however, when deployed via GPO from an Active Directory server (Per-Computer GPO), the installation does not complete. (Everything except the INF install completes).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is a modified version of the RUNDLL32.exe command. Change the 132 to 131

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 131 path-to-inf\infname.inf
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957(v=vs.85).aspx

128 + 4 = 132 = Ask the user to reboot if required
128 + 3 = 131 = Don't ask just reboot

Since this is being deployed from AD and installed on boot before any user is logged on, I imagine it fails when the program tries to create a popup box to ask if the user would like to shutdown. Making it 131 causes it to install and reboot the computer all before a user can log on. After the computer is done with the double reboot it's good to go.